# open pdf in internet-explorer-8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a file Life.pdf in the directory

\10.230.193.131\dev\Reports

From my window explorer I am able to browse the folder and I can open the file\10.230.193.131\dev\Reports\Life.pdf ,  manually.

Now in my html page I am having a link to open the file

**"open
 file"**

When I point mouse on the link in the left bottom corner of the browser it is also written like

```
file://10.230.193.131/dev/Reports/Life.pdf
```

But on clicking on the link , the pdf file is not opening.
No warning is also displayed.

But when my click on the link from my friend's system, he is able to open the file.
What can I do to make it openable form my system ?

Note we both are in same network and both can access the file 
\10.230.193.131\dev\Reports\Life.pdf using file browser/window explorer.

I just need to make it openable from  ie 8 and above.

Comment: the link is rendered like <a href="\\10.230.193.131\dev\reports\Life.xls" target="_blank">open file<a>

Answer (score 1):

Please try: `<a href="http://10.230.193.131/dev/reports/Life.xls" target="_blank">open file<a>`

Thanks.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1762020/4798246.aspx/1?Re+open+pdf+in+internet+explorer+8