# How to make link button work on Internet explorer 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have created a button link that works on `Google Chrome` and `Firefox` but does not work on `Internet Explorer 11`. I am just getting a simple `pdf` with the `a href`.

```
<a href="Calendar.pdf" class="btn btn-primary"> Calendar</a>
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what actually happens?

Comment: So, I have a pdf file in my folder that it gets viewed when a button is clicked. But, On IE when you click on to open the pdf it does not open and goes to index

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please incorporate your comment into the original question. Also, did you search the site before you posted your question? This could well be a duplicate [stackoverflow.com/questions/8984419/open-pdf-in-internet-explorer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984419/open-pdf-in-internet-explorer-8/8985245)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="window.location.replace('Calendar.pdf')" class="btn btn-primary"> Calendar</a>
```

If it does not work try the full location to the Calendar.pdf

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your output? What do you mean with *I am just getting a simple pdf with the a href*?

I put your code in a CodePen and if I run it through Browserstack I get the exact same result as I am on Chrome:

[Result on IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcjdi.png)

Comment: So, I have a pdf file in my folder that it gets viewed when a button is clicked. But, On IE when you click on to open the pdf it does not open and goes to `index`

Comment: I see. Have you tried including the full path to your PDF in your href? I.e. http://www.website.com/folder/calendar.pdf. And is this an issue occurring with all other links to PDFs on your machine? It may just be an Adobe Reader issue: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html.